# Code Igniter - carts library random works

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’m using a cart library to get orders in my web bookstore. But when I call a addCart function on one of my book it’s works, but not all the time. Please, help

There is my model function:

```
function get_books_by_ID($id)
{
    $this->db->where('BOOK_ID', $id);

    $query =  $this->db->get('books');
    return $query;
    echo vardump($query);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function addCards($id=1)
{
    $query = $this->Kategorie_model->get_books_by_ID($id);
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $item = $query->row(); 
        $data = array(
            'id'      => $item->BOOK_ID,
            'qty'     => 1,
            'price'   => $item->BOOK_Price,
            'name'    => $item->BOOK_Title
        );
        $this->cart->insert($data);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<tr>
<td class="color"><b>Cena: </b><?php echo $data->BOOK_Price;?>zł</td>
<td class="border" id="koszyk" ><?php echo anchor('ksiegarnia/addCards/'.$data->BOOK_ID, 'Koszyk'); ?></td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE:**

`vardump` is nothing necessary. I want to use var_dump. But the problem is related with adding items to the session with carts library. I have a bookstore, and when I call a `addCarts` function, sometimes items is added to Carts, and cart function total() and total_items displaying it, but sometimes when I call function, nothing is happened. The items not add into carts. I don't now why this thing have a place. Why the carts library works randomly?

Comment: Please, fix the formatting and explain the problem (why it does not work? Is there an error message?).

Comment: Do you load the model in the construct? Kategorie_model

Comment: Is `vardump` a your own function? in php exists `var_dump` and you are dumping something after a `return ` statement

Comment: Keep in mind that cookies can only store 4k.. you might be overloading the session cookie if you are not saving to db.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue and it seems that in the codeigniter cart library the insert function checks the product(s) id and name against a regex only allow alpha-numeric, dashes, underscores and periods

Adjust the regex to what may come up:

$this->cart->product_id_rules = '.a-z0-9_';

$this->cart->product_name_rules = '.\:-_ a-z0-9';

In my case it would randomly add thing to carts too. If you turn on logging and check you'll be able to see that the name or id may contain invalid chars

Answer (score 0):

i am doing as you did, and like you said, the cart is randomly works,
it seems can only contain 3 product in cart when i add another product, the product i added wont get into cart..

i am so hopeless, i get mind to change cart libraries with 3rd party

it is because i did not setting session to save to database, like in the tutorial (cart & session) the cart need session to write to database in order to work.

when i set session write to database, the problem solved

you can try...